# Error setting `items` and target action when subclassing UISegmentControl

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol

In the following code I have a few `UISegmentControl`s that I'm creating programmatically, all of the segments are the same, except for the target action. What I would like to be able to do is move the code for the segment controls to its own class but I ran into a couple of issues.

How can I set the `items` and the target action when subclassing `UISegmentControl`?

FYI - The items are the same for all of them.

#### This is the code I want to move to its own class.

```
let segmentOne: UISegmentedControl = {
    let items = ["One" , "Two"]
    let segment1 = UISegmentedControl(items: items)
    segment1.selectedSegmentIndex = 0

    segment1.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
    segment1.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
    segment1.layer.borderWidth = 1
    segment1.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor

    segment1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(segmentDiscountTwoType), for: .valueChanged)
    return segment1
}()
```

#### This is what I have tried that gives me two errors:

First ERROR:

> 'super.init' called multiple times in initializer

Second ERROR:

> Argument of '#selector' cannot refer to parameter 'actionName'

```
import UIKit

class MySegmentControl: UISegmentedControl{

    init(actionName: Selector){
        let discountItems = ["One" , "Two"]

        super.init(frame: .zero)
        super.init(items:discountItems)// first ERROR

        self.selectedSegmentIndex = 0

        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor

       self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(actionName), for: .valueChanged) // second ERROR
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First ERROR:

Don't call `init(frame`

Second ERROR:

`actionName` is already a `Selector`

```
class MySegmentControl: UISegmentedControl {

    init(actionName: Selector) {
        let discountItems = ["One" , "Two"]
        super.init(items: discountItems)

        self.selectedSegmentIndex = 0

        self.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
        self.layer.borderWidth = 1
        self.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor

        self.addTarget(self, action: actionName, for: .valueChanged)
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

Comment: @ vadian - Your solution got rid of the errors listed above but now when I try to instantiate I get error... *Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x102eb7784)*  -  **Fatal error: Use of unimplemented initializer 'init(frame:)' for class MyApp.MySegmentControl'**

Comment: That's another question and depends on the context.

Comment: I'll post a different question. Quick question, in theory where do you usually go to find information on how to subclass as certain UIKit class? The documentation for `UISegmentedControl` doesn't say anything. Sorry about the silly question but I always struggle with subclassing.

Comment: But as I said, the documentation for UISegmentedControl doesn't say anything.

Comment: `UISegmentedControl` inherits from `UIControl` which inherits from `UIView`